# jQuery Mobile 1.4+ pagecontainer

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Perhaps someone here could shed some insights into the behavior outlined below

**WORKS** -i.e. the page with id #pageAlreadyInDOM is displayed

```
 $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','#pageAlreadyInDOM');
```

**PAGE IS LOADED** but not shown

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('load','external.html');
```

as verified by checking

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerload',function(e,ui){console.log(ui.toPage);});
```

take that one step further and do

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerload',function(e,ui)
{$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','#externalPageID');;});
```

does nothing - i.e the page with the id #externalPageID is not shown

At the same time this

```
<a href='external.html' data-role='button'>Load External</a>
```

works perfectly - i.e the page resource at external.html gets loaded, enhanced and displayed as expected.

And finally

```
$('#pgInternal').remove();
```

with

```
$('body').on('pagecontainerremove',function(e,ui){console.log(ui.toPage);console.log('page removed');})
```

does not produce the expected console messages.

should

Comment: It looks I was mistaken, it's possible to use both hash and filename http://plnkr.co/edit/Gi2ZewT09YgoQZCSFWPi?p=preview Edit: Change page by ID works one time only. Change page by filename works with no issues.

Comment: hash works one time only because page is removed from DOM once hidden unless its cached.

Comment: Thanks Omar - some very insightful comments.

Comment: You're welcome, my answer is useless since the code above should work fine. The demo says it all :)